# Neither,nor logic question.

Tags: logic

I have a question on sentential logic. I have the following sentence that needs to be translated:

"Pudding is neither good nor fattening."

G=Pudding is good.
F=Pudding is fattening.

I gave the following answer : not G and not F
But it seems that the real answer is : not(G or F)

Wouldn't the two be equivalent ? If we consider "or" to mean both G and F,(In this case) then we are really saying the same thing. Aren't we ? By the way, my knowledge of logic is minimal, so try to talk in a way with someone who's only learning. Thank yoU!

Comment: They are equivalent, but that doesn't mean they are both translations of the same sentence.

Comment: So, my answers would be no problem?

Comment: I'm hinting that you're answer might not be correct. Consider the statements *Every creature with a heart is mortal* and  *Every creature with a kidney is mortal*. Would you translate them in the same way? Probably not, yet, since every creature has a kidney if, and only if, it has a heart, they are equivalent.

Comment: In any case, I think that if one of the translations is better than the other, yours is better. Your answer is correct.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent; that is De Morgan's Law, which states that 
\begin{equation*}
\neg (A \vee B )=\neg A \wedge \neg B
\end{equation*}
where $\vee$ is or, $\wedge$ is and, and $\neg$ is not.