# How to correctly apply probability multiplication and addition laws?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to apply the probability addition rule to the problem below.

There are 12 different socks in a drawer.
The table below shows the different varieties:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Thickness | chunky (C) or thin (T) |
| Style | stripy (S) or dotty (D) or plain (P) |
| Colour | red (R) or blue (B) |

| Thickness | Style | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | S | R |
| C | S | B |
| C | D | R |
| C | D | B |
| C | P | R |
| C | P | B |
| T | S | R |
| T | S | B |
| T | D | R |
| T | D | B |
| T | P | R |
| T | P | B |

Based on the table, some simple observations:

- Probability that a chunky sock is taken out: 6:12
- Probability that a stripy red sock is taken out: 2:12

This is where i'm getting confused based on applying the laws:

- Probability that a dotty and red sock is taken out:

  - probability of dotty sock = 4:12
  - probability of red sock = 6:12
  - applying multiplication law, probability of dotty and red sock = 4/12 * 6/12 = 1:6
  - **1:6 seems to correctly reflect observed data in table, so I assume multiplication law is correctly applied in this case?**
- Probability that a sock that is neither plain nor blue is taken out:

  - probability of plain sock = 4:12
  - probability of blue sock = 6:12
  - applying addition law, probability of plain or blue sock = 4/12 + 6/12 = 10:12
  - therefore probability of neither plain or blue sock is everything else i.e 2:12 = 1:6
  - observed data in table suggest this should be 4:12 = 1:3
  - **What might be wrong in my understanding of the problem and/or application of the addition law?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that a dotty and red sock is taken is 1:6 is correct.
The mistake in the second method:
Let A be one event and B be the second event.
Neither A nor B means (not A) and (not B)
The probability that neither A nor B is selected is $P($not $A) \cdot P($not $B)$
In your case, 
Probability that a sock that is neither plain nor blue is taken out = $P($not blue$) \cdot P($not plain$)$
P(not blue)= $1 - \frac{6}{12} = \frac{1}{2}$
P(not plain) =  $1 - \frac{4}{12} = \frac{2}{3}$
Probability that a sock that is neither plain nor blue is taken out = $\frac{1}{3}$

Hope this helps

EDIT:
P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)
P(A and B) = P(A).P(B) only when A and B are independent. Independent means that an effect on A does not affect B.

Basically
P(neither A nor B) = 1- P(A or B) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) +P(A and B)
Now in this question, A and B are independent so P(A and B) = P(A)P(B)
So,
P(neither A nor B) = 1- P(A or B) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) +P(A)P(B)
$---------------------------------------$
Also,
P(neither A nor B) = not(P(A)) and not (P(B))
So,
P(neither A nor B) = (1 - P(A))(1 - P(B)) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) +P(A)P(B)
You get the same result in both cases.
If you have any more doubts you can ask in the comment

Comment: Always struggle with that slightly awkward wording, but that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Likely another misunderstanding on my part, but looking at this question/answer:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/824060/neither-nor-logic-question

Answer suggests they are equivalent.

They are equivalent; that is De Morgan's Law, which states that
¬(∨)=¬∧¬

Assume my question differs in some meaningful way from the above?

Comment: @HarryB Do you know the meaning of P(A U B)?

Comment: @HarryB Basically, you are getting confused between P(A)+P(B) and P(A U B)

Comment: @HarryB Where did you learn about the additional law of probability? can you mention the source, please?

Comment: I do understand P(A U B), perhaps not as well as i should. No particular source but I have been trying to follow: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/two-basic-rules-of-probability/. I'm getting a handle on my confusion, thanks for your help.

Comment: @HarryB Do you know the fact that Probability cannot be greater than 1? If yes then think about this: Let there be event A and event B.        P(A) = 2/3. P(B) = 2/3. Then what is P(A or B)? You might say it is 4/3 but the probability cannot be greater than 1

Comment: @HarryB P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B)- P(A and B) This is mentioned in your source also.                           So P(A or B) is not always equal to P(A)+P(B). It is only when P(A and B) =0.

Comment: @HarryB I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to expand and explain, much appreciated. Your last edit and comments cleared up the confusion.